# Mutual dependence of replacement and power set axioms

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read in Gittman, Hamkins, et al, that ZFC without the power set causes the axiom of replacement to fail. Yet I also read (generally, throughout the literature, but mostly in connection with Cantor's theorem) that the power set is generated by *replacing* one set with another. Is the term replacement in the context of the power set informally used? Or does this apparent circularity simply explain why power set and replacement are axiomatic?

Comment: "causes the axiom of replacement to fail" is a gross misunderstanding of the text.

Comment: Thanks. How is it to be understood then?

Comment: Maybe "fail" is too final a word! I see that ZFC without the power set has weaknesses that are repaired by using collection rather than replacement. So does collection work for generating a power set?

Comment: @asaf - I think you scared everyone away!

Comment: As I understand it, one gets a power set by starting with N and applying the function 2^N. Does the use of this function assume the viability of the axiom of replacement? Can anyone clarify this for me? I made a point of posting with the tag "elementary set theory" because I am novice with a sincere question.

Comment: Could you give a reference for where you read "that the power set is generated by replacing one set with another"? The only sensible meaning I can imagine for this statement is that, if we consider some set, then its power set is another set.  That has nothing to do with replacement axioms.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Victoria Gitman's last name has only one "t", and Thomas A. Johnstone is a co-author. Our paper is:

- V. Gitman, J. D. Hamkins, and T. A. Johnstone, [What is the theory ZFC without power set?](http://jdh.hamkins.org/what-is-the-theory-zfc-without-power-set/), under review.

But you haven't described the result correctly. The main result is that many things go completely wrong, if one axiomatizes ZFC without power set using the replacement axiom, instead of the collection axiom plus separation. Although replacement is equivalent to collection plus separation over the usual version of ZFC without those axioms, when one omits the power set axiom this equivalence is no longer true, and there are a number of surprising issues that arise, as we explain in our paper. For example, one cannot prove that $\omega_1$ is regular in the version of ZFC-powerset where one has only replacement and not collection, even though the well-order principle is there, and similarly the Los theorem fails and there are many other problems.

The final conclusion is that the right way to axiomatize ZFC without power set is to use the collection and separation axioms, rather than merely replacement.

Comment: Apologies for misspelling Ms. Gitman's name and for reducing Mr. Johnstone to a figure in the crowd. Thanks too for clarifying the import of this paper. I do think I came closer in my own restatement of it, but as a novice I'm not one to judge. I see that my Ipad is posting when I try to start a new paragraph, so I will have to continue my reply from another computer tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can no longer locate the sources where the power set is described in terms of replacing an original set. But let the intuition be wholly my own, my problem is the same. It really is a beginner's question, I think. Why is the power set P(N) considered not to be a mapping -- not to be a specific case of replacement, and therefore deserving of an axiom of its own?

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the title of the question: The axiom of power set and the axiom schema of replacement are independent of each other. Neither is deducible from the other plus the remaining axioms of ZFC.